# Organizing data base structure

Tags: php, laravel

I have user table in Laravel project. There is a task, every user needs to set minimum 1 and maximum 4 languages they speak. For every language user need to set the level of proficiency. So how to correctly organise that?

I think about few ways:

- Make 8 fields for each language and level, some of them may stay null
- Store in one field some structure like JSON or some else and parse it every time when getting data

Both look like a crutch. Hope that I just don't know something.

I need some best practice solution.

Comment: User table and Language table foreign key in language table is the users id column

Comment: Suggestion: https://www.lynda.com/Access-tutorials/Relational-Database-Fundamentals/145932-2.html?utm_source=google&utm_medium=cpc&utm_campaign=l1-US-Search-IT-Relational+Database&cid=l1-us:en:ps:lp:prosc:s2057:140:all:google:mbm-relational_database_tutorial&utm_content=65092029426&utm_term=%2Brelational%20%2Bdatabase%20%2Btutorial&src=go-pa&veh=skwd-83214329586_pcrid_65092029426_pkw_%2Brelational%20%2Bdatabase%20%2Btutorial_pmt_b_pdv_c_ext__plc__trg__agid_14657628426_cmid_235483506_adp_1t1_net_g&lpk35=9137#tab

Comment: User table; Language table; and a xref table for UserLanguage with user_id, language_id and proficiency columns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [Many to Many relationship](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many)

For example, many users may have the language of "English". To define this relationship, three database tables are needed: `users`, `languages`, and `language_user`.

The `language_user` table is derived from the alphabetical order of the related model names, and contains the `user_id` and `language_id` columns.

The migration to create the `language_user` table:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::table('language_user', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');

        //Language foregn key
        $table->integer('language_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('language_id')->references('id')->on('languages');

        //User foregn key
        $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');

    });
}
```

Define the relationship:

**User Model**

```
class User extends Model
{
    /**
     * The languages that belong to the user.
     */
    public function languages()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Language');
    }
}
```

**Language Model**

```
class Language extends Model
{
    /**
     * The users that belong to the language.
     */
    public function users()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\User');
    }
}
```

And now you have a more clean user/language table and all languages are going to be stored at the language_user.

Ps. I'm assuming you are using a table named `languages` to store the languages, if you dont, you need to create a table and a model too.